# Как создать Timer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Мне нужно создать Timer, что бы тот через случайное время изменял позицию ПрогрессБара на 1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем-то можно, если на самом таймере изменять случайным образом значение его свойства Interval, а к прогрессбару (свойство Position) всегда прибавлять 1.

Comment: Это я понял! Я только не понял, где взять таймер?

Comment: На закладке System (там такие часики): первый компонент этой закладки.

Answer (score 1):

Вкладка System компонент TTimer или CreateTimer() по-моему